# Get `pv` work in `ssh` session

Tags: bash, ssh, pipe

How do I get `pv` to work when called remotely via `ssh`?

E.g.

```
a@a-virtual-machine:~$ ssh user@server.eu "pv < ~/Documents/Local/staging.sql.gz" | gunzip  > /dev/null
```

This prints no usual `pv` progress information. FWIW the remote system is Ubuntu 20.

Comment: In case of this particular command, it's sane to use `cat` instead of the remote `pv` and to put *local* `pv` between `ssh` and `gunzip` in the pipe.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski that's exactly what I was doing but it was still frustrating

Answer (score 4, accepted):

pv only shows its progress bar if it detects a *terminal* (tty) being available on stderr. Use `pv -f` to override this and make it display a progress bar anyway.

```
ssh foo "pv -f largefile.sql.gz" | gunzip > largefile.sql
```

In regular mode `ssh` asks the server to allocate a terminal, but in batch (command) mode it doesn't, as it would corrupt the binary data being transferred.

You could *in other cases* use the `-t` option to enable terminal allocation even in command mode, e.g. you could do `ssh -t user@server htop` to have the command run in a terminal, but in this particular case it's likely to damage the gzipped data.

When pv is being used locally, it has separate 'stdout' that goes to a pipe and 'stderr' that goes to a tty, allowing it to separately output the binary data and the terminal control codes. But with SSH there is unfortunately no way to selectively enable a tty for stderr but not for stdout – either both streams go through tty processing or neither.

Fortunately pv has the `-f` `--force` option to make it display the progress even without a terminal. Without a tty it also has no way to determine how wide your local terminal is; the default of 80 should work well enough but if you want it to look perfect use the `-w` `--width` option.

Comment: Your both options are actually quite useful. Sometimes I need to just run a script over `ssh` that uses `pv` internally, and sometimes I stream data.

Comment: @AntonDuzenko See [`ssh` with separate stdin, stdout, stderr AND tty](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/653431/108618). I used your original command with the `sshe` tool (from my answer there) instead of `ssh` and `pv` simply worked. Messages from `gunzip` may look weird though; it's all explained in the answer.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski thanks, but for my trivial use cases the accepted answer is a simpler solution. I don't need that level of interactivity.